# Display specific Column when checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, checkbox

I would like to display a specific column (date of birth, for an example) on a dataGridView which is connected to MS Access, when a checkbox (date of birth checkbox) is checked. It would help much more if it was an array, because I want to add more than one checkbox.

```
namespace emp_db1
{
    public partial class Print : Form
    {

        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        public Print()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = emp_0.mdb";
        }
        DataTable ds;
        private void Print_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name, DOB FROM emp_per";
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                ds = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(ds);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
                da.Update(ds);
                connection.Close();
                dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
                dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumnHeadersHeight();
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                    col.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                }
                this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
            }
        }
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void dob_check_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
        }
    }
}
```

thankyou.

Comment: why did you delete your previous, identical question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

```
 namespace emp_db1
{
    public partial class Print : Form
{
    List<CheckBox> chkboxes = new List<CheckBox>();


    private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    public Print()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = emp_0.mdb";

    }
    DataTable ds;

    private void Print_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    chkboxes.Add(dob_check); //0
    chkboxes.Add(mother_check); //1

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name, DOB, Mother FROM emp_per";
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            ds = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            da.Update(ds);
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumnHeadersHeight();

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                col.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                col.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            }
            this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
    }


    private void refreshCheckBoxes(int id)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
        {
            if (!chkboxes[x].Checked) dataGridView1.Columns[x+2].Visible = false; else dataGridView1.Columns[x+2].Visible = true;

        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void dob_check_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        refreshCheckBoxes(0);
    }

    private void mother_check_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        refreshCheckBoxes(1);
    }
    }
}
```